# Flutter. My UI is not updated when I receive a value from a Future Function

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is that when I receive information from Firestore, I see it in the console that it prints but my UI does not update. But until I press the icon that shows my screen again. The screen where my list of widgets is contained in a BottomNavigationBar.

What I hope will happen with the code is that when I select the tab that will contain my screen in the BottomNavigationBar, the list of Widgets appears with the names of the DocumentIDs. Well, currently I must select the tab again so that they appear.

I attach my code.

```
class PruebasVarias extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PruebasVariasState createState() => _PruebasVariasState();
}

class _PruebasVariasState extends State<PruebasVarias> {


  List<String> myData        = [];
  List<Widget> myListWidget  = [];

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    getallDocument();
  }

  Future getallDocument()async{
    final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
                                      .collection("Users")
                                      .getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documentos = result.documents;
    documentos.forEach((data) {
      myData.add(data.documentID);
      print(myData);
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < (myData.length); i++){
      myListWidget.add(Text("${myData[i]}"));
    } 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text("Documents"),
        actions: <Widget>[
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: 
        Column(children: myListWidget),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You either use a FutureBuilder or use setState at the end of your getallDocument method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy fix : use `then`  to call a callback function and inside callback function use `setState` to update the UI.

```
class PruebasVarias extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PruebasVariasState createState() => _PruebasVariasState();
}

class _PruebasVariasState extends State<PruebasVarias> {


  List<String> myData        = [];
  List<Widget> myListWidget  = [];

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    getallDocument().then(()=>updateUI()).catchError((error)=>print(error));
  }

  Future<void> getallDocument()async{
    final QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
                                      .collection("Users")
                                      .getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documentos = result.documents;
    documentos.forEach((data) {
      myData.add(data.documentID);
      print(myData);
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < (myData.length); i++){
      myListWidget.add(Text("${myData[i]}"));
    } 
  }


void updateUI()
{
setState((){});
 
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text("Documents"),
        actions: <Widget>[
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: 
        Column(children: myListWidget.isEmpty?[Text("Waiting...")]:myListWidget),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by calling  `setState(() {})` method; setState
Notify the framework that the internal state of this object has changed.

```
  Future getallDocument() async {
    final QuerySnapshot result =
        await Firestore.instance.collection("Users").getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documentos = result.documents;
    documentos.forEach((data) {
      myData.add(data.documentID);
      print(myData);
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < (myData.length); i++) {
      myListWidget.add(Text("${myData[i]}"));
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: Your answer worked for me too, but the platform doesn't allow me to mark two correct answers. Thank you so much!